# How to get a String of mMap items

Tags: java, android, camera, hardware

In Android Studio I can expand variables in the debug (Variables) window see below,

How can I get access, programmatically, to the values within `params` listed in `mMap`

[image: mMap expanded]

Answer (score 0):

To get zoom: `int zoom = params.getZoom()`.
If you want all the values: `String values = params.flatten()`.
For details see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html.

Comment: No sorry tried that, flatten gives a subset for instance iso-values doesn't show up, the purpose is to list options that are not in the API

Comment: Did you try `params.get(key)`?

Comment: What is the value of key(s)? I cannot get a `LIST` of the `key`s. If I got a LIST of keys I can cycle through the list for the values. **SO** how do I get a list of keys

Comment: So you are not looking for some specific value and want to know all the parameters? If you are looking for some specific values, you can have a list of hard-coded keys and try them. Otherwise, it seems difficult.